# How to access Javascript set URL attribute from Spring Controller?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc

Following is the Javascript function which is using AJAX call in my Spring MVC application :-

```
    function someAjax(){


    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    http.open("GET", "AjaxSameUser?username="+username, true);

    http.onreadystatechange=handleResponse;
    http.send(null);
}
```

"AjaxSameUser" is RequestMapped to a Controller, which redirects to AjaxSameUser.jsp.

I am also able to get static content from AjaxSameUser.jsp and use it using http.responseText.

Now, I want to access username in this Controller. How do I do this??

Actually this is the username of a signup page. I want to check whether the username entered by user is already present in the current database.

I have tried using @ModelAttribute considering that username would be set in the request scope. But I am not able to access this value set from Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
public String method(@RequestParam("username") String userName) {..}
```

If the username is optional, Use

```
public String method(@RequestParam(value="username", required=false) String userName) {..}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @RequestParam(value = "username") in your Controller's method signature.

regards
Grzegorz Grzybek